# Control iPhone Remotely

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, cellular-carriers, mobile-device-management

Can you control an iPhone remotely using Mobile Device Management protocol? or any other protocol/service? Of course, the user's consent will be obtained before performing any actions.
I am mainly interested in changing the settings and manually selecting a carrier on behalf of the user. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings have many MDM hooks. You can experiment for free cloud based solution like JAMF now to get started.

- https://signup.jamfcloud.com

Carrier settings are much more tricky, most get set by the carrier over the air and depend on whatever sim is sent out and physically installed, so you’ll likely need something other than a MDM for that.

Comment: by carrier settings, I meant network selection settings. I would like to switch the network selection mode to manual and select a specific carrier. Can that be done using MDM?

Comment: I know of no mdm call for that, but I haven’t seen the technical specification for a couple years. No MDM I currently use does that @MohamadAliMhaidly. That’s the sort of thing I would totally put in the answer if I knew for sure you could control that. Your best bet is having users put in the proper sim.

Answer (score 1):

If you have setup the iPhone already using the [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) you can remotely change settings or remotely wipe the device. The idea being you have control of the device because you own it, therefore you are able to control the device from anywhere. Otherwise apple devices don't really allow remote control.

See this article for more information on how to remotely configure a device [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-apple-configurator-2-to-simplify-deploying-ios-upgrades-ota/).

Comment: only Apple Configurator 2? nothing else, right?

Comment: Yes, unless you are talking about jailbroken phones.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to Apple Configurator 2,  you can use the [Profile Manager in macOS Server](https://support.apple.com/profile-manager) to use the MDM protocol. [This article](https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.4/#/apd05B9B761-D390-4A75-9251-E9AD29A61D0C) explains how. Apple will most likely be adding more features for MDM and similar things in the future as inferred from [Apple's recent article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208312) on changes to macOS Server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot remotely control an iOS device. However, many things can be configured, including SOME Carrier Settings (namely APN settings for data - not selecting specific carriers), using a Mobile Device Management product (options include MobileIron, XenMobile, AirWatch, Apple Profile Manager, Lightspeed, JAMF, etc). If you are using a device configured with Apple School Manager and [Classroom](https://www.apple.com/education/docs/getting-started-with-classroom-2.0.pdf) you can also view the screens.

Some settings can only be configured if you have [supervised](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202837) the device, which can be done either with Apple Configurator, or with the Device Enrollment Program.